# DevExtreme FileUploader Not Working Modal

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, devextreme

When I upload it on the pages, your question does not work in the running devextreme fileupload modal part, it gives the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dxFileUploader is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:1:38)
    at j (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
```

My Code:

```
@(Html.DevExtreme().FileUploader()
            .Name("File")
            .Accept("*")
            .Multiple(true)
                        )
```

Comment: The error is regarding the JS code, not the C# in your view, so the example isn't the cause. However, the problem is because the view does not have a reference to the JS file which includes the `dxFileUploader` jQuery plugin. Add that and it will fix the issue.

Comment: Read this: https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t411884/fileuploader-mvc-wrapper-how-to-upload-a-file-with-an-extra-parameter